# Python socket causing hang

Tags: python, sockets

Occasionally my python App hangs when there is a burst of send/receive on the socket.
What am I missing here: seems basic:

```
skt.send(packet)
```

and

```
skt.recv_into(pkt)
```

If a put a sleep(0.2) after the call, then it works fine.

Should I change to the select() way of talking to socket?
I have tried 2.7 to 3.3 which seems to be better, but still that hang occurs.

The socket is setup as:

```
skt = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

skt.connect((ipAddress, nwPort))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is far too little information to tell. I don't think there's a hang, but a sleep pending data (which you could disable with MSG_DONTWAIT or [setblocking](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking), or another check such as select) when you read, because data isn't present yet. If you know it has been sent, it's possible it's in various network delays, particularly [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) which you can disable with TCP_NODELAY. You should generally use select or poll if you want your program to be responsive - note that for a stream protocol like TCP, you'll need to combine it with nonblocking behaviour if you don't know the exact sizes arriving ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of `socket.recv_into(buffer[, nbytes[, flags]])` specifies that:

> Receive up to nbytes bytes from the socket, storing the data into a
>   buffer rather than creating a new bytestring. If nbytes is not
>   specified (or 0), receive up to the size available in the given
>   buffer.

Try to be more specific in how many bytes for data you're actually receiving from the socket by setting `nbytes` to a number of bytes. Typically, messages are either delimited (e.g. by `CRLF`) so even if you allow fewer bytes on `recv` function you can just wait for the delimiter to arrive; or they are fixed-length, in which case you just set to that byte-length (or slightly over it).